# Issue with Updating in Ubuntu 12.04 Running on Flash Drive

Tags: apt

I am trying to update the packages on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which is running on a flash drive.  I tried in the command: `sudo apt-get update` and receive the following error:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04.3%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20130820.1)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04.3%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20130820.1)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)'
```

How can I fix this problem so the system can update packages correctly?

Comment: Have you tried removing the duplicates from the sources.list file?

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu. How would I go about this process?

Answer (score 0):

From experiencing a similar problem in the past it be could be lack of space on the flash drive. It processes then gives that error at the end. Do you have enough space on your flash drive?.

Comment: There should be enough space. It's a 32 Gb flash drive.